# Change permissions on folders (mass)

Tags: windows, security, permissions, windows-server-2008

I've had some problems in my server and now I need to give some write-permissions on some folders, but I have a lot of folders to do it.

My server is Windows Server 2008, and if I select all folder make a right-click and properties, there's no tab 'Security' to change permissions, I can do it one by one but I lost much time.

Is there any way to give these permissions on my folder fastly ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some options, although Im surprised selecting a group and right clicking doesnt give you security.. Anyway

Check out icacls.

```
icacls c:\windows\* /save AclFile /T
- Will save the ACLs for all files under c:\windows
  and its subdirectories to AclFile.

icacls c:\windows\ /restore AclFile
- Will restore the Acls for every file within
  AclFile that exists in c:\windows and its subdirectories.

icacls file /grant Administrator:(D,WDAC)
- Will grant the user Administrator Delete and Write DAC
  permissions to file.

icacls file /grant *S-1-1-0:(D,WDAC)
- Will grant the user defined by sid S-1-1-0 Delete and
  Write DAC permissions to file.
```

Comment: No, pitfal is that it does not shows Security tab when selecting group of files and/or folders.

Answer (score 0):

VBscript. That's the old school Windows way.

Server 2008 comes with Powershell.  Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my scripts for automating this task:

https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/utils/ci/tip/tree/win/uac/

Put both script to directory and run **uac.js**. For all hierarchy belong this directory scripts restore ownership and grand full access for All.