# How to regain USB disks folders permissions after switching to Win7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I have a problem after upgrading my comp and installing Windows 7. Prior to that I did used Windows XP (SP3) and made a lot of data backups on external HDDs. Now comes the problem - those backups were made by WinXP account and now in Win7 I can't rename/delete any of files/folders.

I know this is caused by ownership issues, to make things right again I have to change folders (and it sub-folders and files) owner to my existing Win7 account. The problem is - I can't select all of the USB drives folders together (in group selection there's no security tab in properties), I have to go one-by-one and that is my question: Is there a way to automate this somehow, how do I change ownership (or remove it altogether) from dozen of drives and hundreds of folders and files?

On a side note, there are few autorun.inf files from viruses my antivirus has deleted, but the files remained and they are not allowing me to change ownership/edit/delete them at all, even from admins account. So best answer would be a kind of tool or way to remove all permission limitations at once.

P.S. After I typed all this SE offered me similar question: [Change permissions on folders (mass)](https://superuser.com/questions/306594/change-permissions-on-folders-mass) , but I'm not sure this is exact answer, what to do with ownership?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [page](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/take-ownership-of-file-or-folder-windows-7-vista/) that gives a bit more explanation but basically you need to do

```
takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y
```

which hopefully will accept wildcards then

```
icacls <foldername> /grant administrators:F /T
```

from a command prompt that you ran as an administrator.

Comment: It worked best this way: icacls <foldername> /grant (:MA) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my scripts for automating this task:

https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/utils/ci/tip/tree/win/uac/

Copy both to dir and run **uac.js**.

Put both script to directory and run uac.js. For all hierarchy belong this directory scripts restore ownership and grand full access for All.

Comment: See also my related question: http://superuser.com/questions/353739/have-issue-with-access-denied-invalid-descriptor-and-external-storage-for-w